# Symfony and Sonata get Class with "pcode"

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm having problem to get the Class which is called by the 'Add New' and the Modal Window.

The situation is that, I have a 'Add New' button on my entry with sonata_type_model:

```
->add('rfid', 'sonata_type_model', array(
                'class' => 'Admin\IdManageBundle\Entity\RFID',
                'property' => 'barcode'
            ))
```

when I click on 'Add New' it shows me a Modal Window, with which I can create new RFID.

but my RFID class has a **barcode** object that must be filled with the data of the class had the 'Add New' button!

I can handle the parent class with

```
->add('barcode', 'text', array(
                'data' => $this->getRequest()->get('pcode')
            ))
```

but I want to be able to get the **Entity Manager** of the responded 'pcode'
In my case **$this->getRequest()->get('pcode')** returns:

> admin_product_accessory_audio_audio.admin.audio

and it's not readable by **$this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository(*$this->getRequest()->get('pcode')*)**

It has made me crazy!! :D

thanks in advance

Comment: not 100 sure, as im not looking at code atm,   but i believe, you have to first fetch the admin object for that admin (the one you got in pcode), then fetch the entityclass from that particular admin,   wich you can the use as an argument for getRepository  (wich needs an entityname, not your 'adminname')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$admin = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getAdminByAdminCode('admin_product_accessory_audio_audio.admin.audio');
$className = $admin->getClass();
$repo = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository($class);
```

making sense ?